# Filter date from current date to upcoming 7 days?

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I have a week type calendar view. It currently displays form SUN to SAT of the current week.

But I need to display it starting from **current date** to **current date + 7 days**

How can I achieve this?.  I am using [Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar) Module and created a view using it.

My view is displayed only if I add a contextual filter. With default value as `current date`. This adds a filter criteria from dates starting from the start of the week and end of the week.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Views filters find your date field.
2. Now, in filter settings select "is between".
3. Choose "Enter a relative date" and enter "Now" in the first one and "+7 days" in the second field.

Comment: My view is displayed only if I add a contextual filter. With default value as current date. This adds a filter criteria from dates starting from the start of the week and end of the week.